# Pyschools Prime factorization

Tags: python, operators

I'm doing the pyschools practices and i have a problem at Topic 5 question 12 - Prime Factorization, i have to do this:

Given a positive integer, write a function that computes the prime factors that can be multplied together to get back the same integer.

```
Examples

  >>> primeFactorization(60)
  [2, 2, 3, 5]
  >>> primeFactorization(1050)
  [2, 3, 5, 5, 7]
  >>> primeFactorization(1)
  []
```

This is my code:

```
import operator
import functools as fun

def primeFactorization(num): 
    num = num
    primes = []
    result = []
    if num > 1:
        [primes.append(x) for x in range(2, num) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x))]
    multy = fun.reduce(operator.mul, result, 1)
    for number in primes:
        if num % number == 0 and multy != num:
            result.append(number)
    return result
```

Which returns me this:

```
Test Cases              Expected Result    Returned Result
primeFactorization(33)  [3, 11]            [3, 11]  
primeFactorization(84)  [2, 2, 3, 7]       [2, 3, 7]    
primeFactorization(1)   []                 []
```

I've tryed this and i'm getting Private Test Case failed:

```
import operator
import functools as fun

def primeFactorization(num): 
    num = num
    primes = []
    result = []
    if num > 1:
        [primes.append(x) for x in range(2, num) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x))]
    multy = fun.reduce(operator.mul, result, 1)
    for number in primes:
        if num % number == 0:
            result.append(number)

    multy = fun.reduce(operator.mul, result, 1)
    y = num/multy
    if y != 1 and y in primes:
        result.insert(0, int(y))
    return result

Test Cases              Expected Result Returned Result
primeFactorization(33)  [3, 11]         [3, 11] 
primeFactorization(84)  [2, 2, 3, 7]    [2, 2, 3, 7]    
Private Test Cases      Passed          Failed  
primeFactorization(1)   []              []
```

What can i do to pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why make it so complicated?
The problem of finding all prime factors of a given number `X` is the same as to find the set of the smallest numbers (that are larger than 1) that we can divide `X` into.
To solve the problem we can start by finding the smallest number `n` that divides `X`.
This is the first prime factor of `X`. We can then find the rest of the prime factors by finding the prime factors of `X/n`

```
def primeFactorization(X):

    possible = [2] + range(3,int(ceil(sqrt(X)))+1,2)

    for p in possible:
        if X % p == 0:
            return [p] + primeFactorization(X/p)

    return [X]


primeFactorization(3*3*7*5*11*13*31)

> [3,3,5,7,11,13,31]
```

Comment: alright, it worked, the only thing was primeFactorization(1)   []              [1] which i made an if and it worked, good job thank you :)